# How do I add an additional route?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

Here is my default route.

```
context.MapRoute(
"CreditReview",
"Site/{sitecode}/CreditReview/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
new { action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

I'm looking to add 'status'.  This is what I currently have and it isn't working.  I haven't worked with routes before so I'm sorry if this is an easy question to answer.

```
context.MapRoute(
 "CC",
 "Site/{sitecode}/CreditReview/{controller}/{status}/{action}/{id}",
 new { action = "Index", id = "" });
```

Comment: What order do you have them in?  I think the second one should be first.  Least specific routes go before most specific routes.  Also can you give an example URL that you are trying to route for both of your MapRoutes?

Comment: I have the default route listed last.  An example of a url that matches the default route is as follows:
http://localhost/CreditCoachPlus.Site/Site/ABC123/CreditReview/PersonalInformation/Info

An example of what I'm trying to get to work is as follows:
http://localhost/CreditCoachPlus.Site/Site/ABC123/CreditReview/PersonalInformation/Info/Correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Obalix's suggestions, Phil Haack's [routing debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) is great for these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the order of the rules is important, custom rules have to be added **before** the default rule.

Then, if that does not work you might try to modify the rule so that it should be a bit more distinguisable.

**Edit**

If these are the routes you going to match

```
http://localhost/CreditCoachPlus.Site/Site/ABC123/CreditReview/PersonalInformation/Info
http://localhost/CreditCoachPlus.Site/Site/ABC123/CreditReview/PersonalInformation/Info/Correct
```

Then why not just adding the status to your default rule and set a default status?

```
context.MapRoute(
    "CreditReview",
    "Site/{sitecode}/CreditReview/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{status}",
    new { action = "Index", id = "", status="notCorrect" }
);
```

Comment: I have the default route listed last.  An example of a url that matches the default route is as follows:
http://localhost/CreditCoachPlus.Site/Site/ABC123/CreditReview/PersonalInformation/Info

An example of what I'm trying to get to work is as follows:
http://localhost/CreditCoachPlus.Site/Site/ABC123/CreditReview/PersonalInformation/Info/Correct